# Migrate Odoo V8 to V12

Tags: postgresql, odoo

There are several ways to upgrade from V8 what I read on several fora.

One of the methods is do exports of "main tables"
Which tables? And it only works good with smaller DB's.
And how big is big ? I have only Accounting , CRM, and Website modules on my Odoo 8 and I am self employed, not an enterprise.

I know that you can easily upgrade from 8 - > 10 .
If I use the OpenUpgrade software, does it make a new DB which can then be used with a new instance of Odoo with V12?  Or does it migrate the complete instance db + software?

If I downgrade modules in V10, will the upgrade to V12 be easy. Or are there special tables written in the DB who can block the migration from V10 -> V12 ?

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are tricky. The basic process will be:

1. Make a copy of your database and ship it to a separate environment
2. Run OpenUpgrade V9.0 with the `--upgrade=all` flag on the database
3. If you come across any errors, handle them individually by looking at the error and making the necessary changes to your modules
4. Once the upgrade completes, you can move forward and do the same for OpenUpgrade V10.0, V11.0 and V12.0
5. Copy your database back to production